# SharePoint 2010 with PerformancePoint, Excel Services and Reporting Services References

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, performancepoint, sharepoint-branding

I've recently been tasked with becoming the SharePoint 2010 expert.  However, to also include PerformancePoint Services (PPS), Excel Services and integration of Reporting Services(SSRS).  Key points regarding PPS is Decomposition Tree and Show Details.  The use of SSRS would be beyond the traditional Report Viewer but to, from what I understand, to return graphs which then are used in PPS.

The next item I needs to learn is Branding; specifically from two angles.  First, Branding a single site (site collection), for example an intranet.  The next would be an internet site where Branding is based upon the user login or by url.  An example of this might be each customer has it's own domain/sub-domain and each has it's own Branding.  However, all of which is hosted by the same SharePoint instance.

My question is, since I have to do this quickly, what would you recommend as must have references?  This could include How-To's, Tutorials, Blogs, Books, Video's, etc.  By the way, I love video's.  I'm a visual and hands on type person.

Never the less, thanks for your thoughts!
Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are also interested in learning SharePoint 2010 and PerformancePoint Services 2010, here are some helpful links:

Online

- SharePoint Training Index: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/CL010257455.aspx
- SharePoint Training: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/CH010372432.aspx
- SharePoint Lists: http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=383
- SharePoint Pro IT Training: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee410529
- SharePoint Advanced IT Training: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff678054.aspx
- SharePoint Business Intelligence Training: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/hh239866
- SharePoint Developer Training: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/aa905692
- SharePoint Advanced Developer Training: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff420385.aspx

Books:

- [Microsoft SharePoint 2010, Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672333252)
- [SharePoint 2010 Administrator's Companion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627207)
- [Pro SharePoint 2010 Business Intelligence Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430232854)
- [SharePoint 2010 Business Intelligence, 24-Hour Trainer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/111802642X)
- [SharePoint 2010 Development with Visual Studio 2010](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321718313)
- [Professional SharePoint 2010 Branding and User Interface Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470584645)